# How to return an AsyncResult in a long running method

Tags: c#

I have a method that creates a file of random size and would like to output the status progress of how far the progress of the file being created. Below is the method used:

```
   public IAsyncResult CreateRandomFile(string destPath, int bytesUsed)
    {

        byte[] dataArray = new byte[bytesUsed];
        new Random().NextBytes(dataArray);


            using (FileStream destStream = new FileStream(destPath, FileMode.Create))
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < dataArray.Length; i++)
                {
                    destStream.WriteByte(dataArray[i]);


                    /// I am not sure how to return or use IAsyncResult such that
                    /// I will be able to access the status of how many bytes have 
                    /// been copied

                    IAsyncResult++;
                }
            }



        return ias;
    }
```

How can I return the `IASyncResult` properly?

Comment: Is there any reason for using `IAsyncResult` over `Task`?

Comment: `IAsyncResult` based asynchrony is a very old pattern that has been superseded by (generally) `Task` - but *neither* of them offers progress reporting. If you need progress reports, you might be looking instead for e.g. a `BackgroundWorker`.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever No need for poor `BackgroundWorker` api. `IProgress<T>` and `Task` combination works well.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever the `BackgroundWorker` class has been superseded by (generally) `Task` - but _neither_ of them offers progress reporting. If you need progress reports, you might be looking instead for `IAsyncOperationWithProgress<TResult, TProgress>` in Windows RT or `IProgress<T>`